# View is not getting rendered without scrolling

Tags: react-native

I have a really weird rendering bug in my app.
The Entry screen is supposed to show title, an image and the authors name (a header view). But the view element only gets displayed after scrolling.

```
<View style={this.state.baseStyles.body}>
<View style={headerStyles.header}>
    <View style={headerStyles.headerSide}>
        <FastImage
            style={headerStyles.headerImage}
            source={{uri: imgUrl}}
            />
    </View>
    <View style={headerStyles.headerBody}>
            <Text style={headerStyles.headerTextTitle}>{entry["title"]}</Text>
            <Text style={headerStyles.headerTextSubtitle}>{datetime} von {entry["author"]}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
<View style={this.state.baseStyles.body}>
    <WebView
    style={styles.WebViewStyle}  
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={false}
    source={{ html: page}}
    ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
        this.onWebviewPressLink(event);
    }}
    />
</View>    
</View>
```

I have tried to find the cause of the bug by looking and comparing it to older code of the app, but I haven't really changed anything. I have updated RN to 0.57.8 from 0.57.2, I haven't yet tried if I downgrade to 0.57.2 with the same code and see if the problem still occurs.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

When opening Entry:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf2uW.jpg

After scrolling:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDeeu.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help

//added styles
Header

```
view:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor:theme.background.secondary
},
headerHighlight: {
    flex:1,    
},
header: {
    padding:10,
    paddingBottom:3,
    flexDirection:'row',    
    backgroundColor: theme.header.background,
    paddingVertical: 4,
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
},
headerSide:{
    paddingHorizontal:8,
},
headerImage:{
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    marginVertical: 4, 
    borderRadius: 3,
},
headerBody:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column'
},
headerTextTitle: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: '200',
    color: theme.header.text.primary,
    marginTop: 8,
    marginRight: 5
},
headerTextSubtitle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: theme.header.text.secondary
},
```

this.state.baseStyles.body:

```
body: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor:theme.background.secondary
},
```

styles.WebViewStyle:

```
{
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
flex:1,
}
```

Comment: I think in order to answer this, you should probably add here your styles in order to see how the flex-box is rendered.

Comment: can you include the styles?

Comment: I have added the styles. It's nothing fancy, Basicly the WebView is flex:1 and the rest has the height of it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by wrapping a ScrollView around it.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={this.state.baseStyles.body}>
        <WebView
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}  
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={false}
        source={{ html: page}}
        ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
            //console.log(event);
            //console.log("Event URL"+event.url);
            this.onWebviewPressLink(event);
        }}
        />
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

I don't no why this solves it but glade it works now. Would be cool if someone could explain it.

//Little bit prittier

```
<ScrollView style={this.state.baseStyles.body} contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
    <WebView
    style={styles.WebViewStyle}  
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={false}
    source={{ html: page}}
    ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
        //console.log(event);
        //console.log("Event URL"+event.url);
        this.onWebviewPressLink(event);
    }}
    />
</ScrollView>
```